# I have created email in marketing cloud, on submitting email form I want to populate thank you message based on the client language

Tags: email, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have created email in marketing cloud, in email I have Email form, once client fills the details and submits the form I want to populate thank you message based on the client language.
I have created Interactive email page to achieve this, but I'm not able to get URL parameters for language code in interactive email page.
Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Consider updating your question to a [Minimal Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is a very broad and open ended question and without knowing too much about what you're currently working with it will be very difficult to provide constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage, interactive email form doesn't allow you to pass parameters to the cloud page.  That's a limitation on the feature.  However, I noticed we can access the **standard** parameters that are generally available within the cloud page using Personalization Strings

```
%%_SubscriberKey%%
```

Btw, post for all Salesforce related questions on Salesforce Stack Exchange
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/